# Data attribute only returning first value

Tags: php, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to get the body of my page to change color when hovering over some list items. Each list item has its own color stored in a data attribute, which I can see in the chrome inspector. The code is doing what I'd like, but returning only the first color in the list for every item, when I want the body to be the color of each list item.

HTML:

```
 <ul class="menu">
    <?php foreach($page->children() as $subpage): ?>
      <li id="tesq" data-color="<?= $subpage->color() ?>">
        <a href="<?= $subpage->url() ?>">
          <?= html($subpage->title()) ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $("body").css('backgroundColor', function () {
          return $("#tesq").data('color')
        });
    }, function() {
        $("body").css('backgroundColor', 'lightgrey')
    });
  })
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, you are trying to get data attribute from the entire collection so it will return the data attribute value of the first element among the collection.

In addition to that use `class` for a group of elements instead of the `id`(id should be unique in the context - `$("#tesq")` will select only the first element).

So do it based on the hovered element, where you can use `this` inside the event handler callback to refer the eleemnt.

**PHP :**

```
 <ul class="menu">
    <?php foreach($page->children() as $subpage): ?>
      <li class="tesq" data-color="<?= $subpage->color() ?>">
        <a href="<?= $subpage->url() ?>">
          <?= html($subpage->title()) ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
 $(function() {
    $('.tesq').hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("body").css('backgroundColor', function () {
          return $this.data('color')
        });
    }, function() {
        $("body").css('backgroundColor', 'lightgrey')
    });
  })
```

---

The callback is completely unnecessary here and you can avoid it.

```
 $(function() {
    $('.tesq').hover(function() {
        $("body").css('backgroundColor', $(this).data('color'));
    }, function() {
        $("body").css('backgroundColor', 'lightgrey')
    });
  })
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! This is unrelated to the query, so I hope it's allowed: would you happen to know if it's possible to use the data as part of linear gradient, within jquery? Something like this:

`$(".tesq").css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + rgba(255,255,255,0) + ' 0%, ' + $(this).data('color') + ' 100%)');`

Comment: @jack_ `$(".tesq").css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, ' + $(this).data('color') + ' 100%)');`